# proving that graph G is a path

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected, graph-connectivity

I want to prove that the connected graph $G$ with $\delta(G) = 1$ and each vertex has a degree of $1$ or $2$, is a path. Can you tell whether my proof is correct?

Since $G$ is connected, there is a path between all of its vertices.
Suppose that $u_1,\dots,u_i,\dots,u_n$ is a path from $u_1$ to $u_n$ which contains all vertices.

According to the assumption, there could not be a cycle in this path; because if there be a cycle, the degree of one vertex should be greater than $2$ and it's in contrast with the assumption.
So the graph $G$ is a path.

Comment: IMHO 1. more specially, the graph has no cycles because one mere cycle has $\delta(G)=2$ and we have one more besides the cycle which causes the degree can be 3. 2. $\delta(G)=1$ implies it may be a tree with leaves and the proof of the acyclic property verifies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make your proof work if we choose $u_1$ and $u_n$ carefully, but it does not work out of the box. Two problems:

- We cannot assume that a path exists which includes all vertices; we're going to have to pick a path in some other way, then prove that it has this property.
- There are plenty of paths that *don't* include all vertices, so if we're going to be proving this about our path, we want to pick the right path to start with.

So here is how we find the path instead. Since $\delta(G)=1$ there is a vertex of degree $1$. The total number of odd-degree vertices in a graph must be even, so there must be at least one more vertex of degree $1$. Let $s, t$ be two vertices of degree $1$; since $G$ is connected, there is a path $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ with $u_1 = s$ and $u_n = t$.

We know that

- $u_1$ and $u_n$ are incident to $1$ edge of the path, and they have degree $1$, so they have no other edges.
- $u_i$ for $1 < i < n$ is incident to $2$ edges of the path, and it cannot have degree more than $2$, so it has no other edges.

So there are no edges out of $u_1, \dots, u_n$ other than the edges of the path. Since $G$ is connected, there cannot be any other vertices (they would have no way to get to vertices on this path). Therefore the path contains all the vertices and edges of the graph.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing but then realized he did not actually refer to hamilton path because he then tries to prove there is no cycle. If he only considers a path that can visit any vertex any number of time then it is actually true that "connected graph implies there is a path that visits all vertices at least once"

Comment: @cr001 There are different definitions of a path; some allow you to revisit vertices, some don't. But if we're going to be using the path $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ to show that $G$ is a path graph, then it had better be the kind of path that cannot revisit a vertex. (I take the statement "there could not be a cycle" to mean "there could not be non-path edges connecting two vertices of the path.)

Answer (score 0):

You stated

> Suppose that $u_1,...,u_i,...u_n$ is a path from $u_1$ to $u_n$ which contains all vertices.

You cannot assume that such a path exist. Suppose that $G$ is path $v_1v_2\ldots v_n$. Then there is not path from $v_2$ to $v_{n}$ that pass by $v_1$.

you should reason by induction $n$ the number of vertices of $G$

1. if $n=1$ or $n=2$, $G$ is trivially a path
2. Suppose that the statement if true for any graph of order $n\geq 2$. Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n+1$ vertices satisfying the conditions $\delta=1$ and $\Delta\leq 2$. Let $u$ be a vertex of degree 1. $u$ has a unique neighbour $v$ in $G$. 
   As $|V(G)|=n+1>2$, and $G$ is connected, then $v$ has degree 2 in $G$.

Let $H=G\backslash\{u\}$ be the graph $G$ after removing $u$. Then $H$ has order $n$, and in $H$, $v$ has degree 1. Therefore $H$ satisfy the conditions : $\delta_H=1$, $\Delta_H\leq 2$. By induction $H$ is a path, and because $G$ is $H$ adding a neighbour to a vertex of degree 1 (the  leaf $v$) then so is $G$.